# React : How to Re-Render If function is invoked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am working on project , where I am updating the url . Actually It working fine when I click on next button but I want to re-render application when function is invoked . I am new to ReactJS , Could some one please help me how to solve this problem .

I am sorry I am not native speaker , I am sorry if I made mistake in English grammer . Thanks

**Displaying data through this URL Function**

```
urlParams() {
 return `http://localhost:3001/meetups?filter[limit]=${(this.state.Item)}&&
filter[skip]=${this.state.skip}
&&filter[order]=${this.state.sortedData}`;
  }
```

**Full Component Code**

```
        class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      Item: 5,
      skip: 0
    }

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  urlParams() {
    return `http://localhost:3001/meetups?filter[limit]=${(this.state.Item)}&&filter[skip]=${this.state.skip}`
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({skip: this.state.skip + 1})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a href={this.urlParams()}>Example link</a>
        <pre>{this.urlParams()}</pre>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Change link</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.querySelector('div#my-example' ))
```

Comment: Can you please show your `render()` function?

Comment: when you use setState function. It should re-render your view.

Comment: I am using it with button , but in meantime it not re-render

Comment: @RobbieAverill , I updated my question please have a look .

Comment: Please provide more code. This is not sufficient to debug.

Comment: @SundarBan , I updated my question with full compnent code . Please have a look and thanks for your comment

Comment: Your component should only rerender if something actually changed, and you tell your component to change something by using `setState`. I would strongly recommend putting your project to the side for half an hour, turning off all instant messaging apps, etc. and just sitting down to run through https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html, coding along. They put a lot of thought into making sure the tutorial covers all the basics, and you'll understand a lot more about how your own code should work afterwards, too.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, Thanks for your comment . Actually Everything is working fine when I click on next button it give me update data but in initial click when I click on button it not render new data which I want

Comment: So form an [mcve]: throw away all the code and almost all that JSX in your render, and reduce your problem to just "the button" and "a div that shows the raw data", and throw away all the other code that isn't related to this. Then you'll have good code to show in your post, if you haven't found the problem on your own yet by forming that mcve (it's the main reason SO expects you to make one: forming an mcve almost always lets you find the errors on your own)

Answer (score 0):

You *can* force a rerender of your component by calling:

```
this.forceUpdate();
```

However, you have to be careful not to enter a never-ending update cycle.

The usual (recommended) way to rerender is through the necessity of changing your state using `setState`.

**EDIT**

I think want you need is to call getData once you have clicked the table header:

```
getSortedData=()=>{
  console.log("hello clicked")
  this.setState({
    sortedData:'companyName'
  })
  // now invoke getdata which will refresh the data:
  this.getData()
}
```

Comment: Not working ! Actually I want to render update data when I click on button but it let me render new data when I click on next button

Comment: I am changing URL State through this method . Can You please check 
  `  getSortedData=()=>{
    console.log("hello clicked")
    this.setState({
      sortedData:'companyName'
    })
  }`

Comment: is this value changing 'companyName'? or is it the same.. in which case, react won't rerender..

Comment: Yes , I am updating `companyName` value but when I click on button it not working ! when I click on next button it working fine but in initial render it not give me an update result

Comment: Can you please help ?